# multiply driven error from components connection

Tags: vhdl

I want to connect 2 components(trngs and wb_master_switch_2x) together. But I got an ERROR from simulation which is

ERROR: [XSIM 43-3249] Unresolved signal "wb_core4" is multiply driven.

I'm not writing to signal from more than one process, but why i'm getting this ERROR?

The corresponding codes are given below.

Best regards

---

```
  type wb_bus_t is record
    adr : std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- address
    di  : std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- slave input data
    do  : std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- slave output data (7 downto 0)
    we  : std_ulogic; -- write enable
    --sel : std_ulogic_vector(03 downto 0); -- byte enable
    stb : std_ulogic; -- strobe
    cyc : std_ulogic; -- valid cycle
    ack : std_ulogic; -- transfer acknowledge
  end record;

  signal wb_core4 : wb_bus_t;
```

---

```
component trngs
generic (
    NUM_OSCILLATORS : natural-- number of XORed oscillators
  );
port (
    -- gloabl control --
    clk_i_trng      : in  std_ulogic;
    rst_i_trng      : in  std_ulogic;
    -- 32-bit wishbone interface --
    wb_dat_o_trng   : out std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- read data
    wb_dat_i_trng   : in  std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- write data
    wb_we_i_trng    : in  std_ulogic; -- read/write
    wb_stb_i_trng   : in  std_ulogic; -- strobe
    wb_cyc_i_trng   : in  std_ulogic; -- valid cycle
    wb_ack_o_trng   : out std_ulogic; -- transfer acknowledge
    wb_adr_i_trng   : in  std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0)
  );

component wb_master_switch_2x
port(
    wb_clk_i          : in  std_ulogic;
    wb_rstn_i         : in  std_ulogic;
    -- wishbone slave port --
    wb_slave_cyc_o    : out std_ulogic; -- valid cycle
    wb_slave_stb_o    : out std_ulogic; -- valid strobe
    wb_slave_we_o     : out std_ulogic; -- write enable
    --wb_slave_sel_o    : out std_ulogic_vector(03 downto 0); -- byte enable
    wb_slave_addr_o   : out std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- access address
    wb_slave_data_o   : out std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- write data
    wb_slave_data_i   : in  std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0); -- read data
    wb_slave_ack_i    : in  std_ulogic  -- acknowledge
);
end component wb_master_switch_2x;
```

---

```
TRNG: trngs

generic map(NUM_OSCILLATORS => 1
 )
port map(
    -- gloabl control --
clk_i_trng => clk_int,       
rst_i_trng => rst_int,      
-- 32-bit wishbone interface --
wb_dat_o_trng => wb_core4.di,
wb_dat_i_trng => wb_core4.do,
wb_we_i_trng => wb_core4.we,
wb_stb_i_trng => wb_core4.stb,
wb_cyc_i_trng => wb_core4.cyc,
wb_ack_o_trng => wb_core4.ack,
wb_adr_i_trng => wb_core4.adr
);


switch_0: wb_master_switch_2x
    port map(
    wb_clk_i => clk_int,          
    wb_rstn_i => rst_int,              

    -- wishbone slave port --
    wb_slave_cyc_o => wb_core4.cyc,     
    wb_slave_stb_o => wb_core4.stb,    
    wb_slave_we_o => wb_core4.we,     
    --wb_slave_sel_o => wb_core4.sel,    
    wb_slave_addr_o => wb_core4.adr,   
    wb_slave_data_o => wb_core4.do,  
    wb_slave_data_i => wb_core4.di,  
    wb_slave_ack_i => wb_core4.ack    
    );
```

---

Comment: My guess is that the error occurs because `wb_core4` as a whole is connected to outputs of different instances, even though each individual part is only driven by a single instance.

Comment: are you sure you dont connect any of the record fields elsewhere? can you post the whole code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There are no visible drivers for any wb_core4 elements from either the trngs or the wb_master_switch_2x provided. These would be in the bound architectures of the entities to which the component are bound in elaboration.